# Mysql external acces not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a setup of two separate Servers.
On one, there is the Website with its DB and on the other Server there is a DB the website needs to access.
so... both servers are running newest versions of Mysql and pma.
By default if i create a new Database with a user, there is a user with localhost access and one with "%" access being created.
As far as i knew the % means that it can be accessed from anywhere... so why isnt it working?
Pic of pma users: [PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2b5V.jpg)
Pic of error message on the Website:[PIC](http://nifares.net/img/jpg/5a58288a9260b36ab1aabe1a6ea24aee.jpg)

Comment: What kind of servers do you use? Do you have a firewall? What about your iptables? If I understand correctly you use a seperate database and webserver? Or two DB servers?

Comment: Servers are on debian, no extra firewall configured and iptables not altered either,
I use easyscp though... maybe it changed some settings there
I have two seperate servers, both are running a DB but the one that has the website on it needs to connect to the other one...

Comment: What happens when you telnet/curl etc. the used port number (I assume it's the default 3306)?

Comment: When i try to telnet ip with port i get connection refused..

Comment: Have you set the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in your my.cnf?

Comment: address is bound to 127.0.0.1 sooo thats the problem i assume?
as you can only connect from "local"

Comment: Correct, set it to 0.0.0.0 (not your other server's IP) and do a restart (sudo service mysqld restart)

Comment: but wont it affect my easyscp installation?

Comment: It will simply allow connections from all ip addresses.. I recommend using iptables instead of the bind-address my.cnf provides anyways :)

Comment: Created an 'official' answer for anyone having the same problem, please accept it if you will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 in my.cnf and don't forget to restrict access with iptables ;)